# R: how to include a function argument in a file path

Tags: r, function, xlsx

I created a function arcgisrail tht filters my data and save it as excel file.
when i run the function `arcgisrail("Agricultural products")` i want my excel file to be saved as Agricultural products.xlsx

This code saves the file as i.xlsx

Want to know how to include the function argument, in this case 'i', in the file path

```
    arcgisrail <- function(i){
        Rail%>%
        filter(Commodity == i)%>%
        write.xlsx("C:\\New folder\\Analysis\\FolderforARCGIS\\i.xlsx",
                   sheetName = "Sheet1",
                   col.names = TRUE,
                   row.names = TRUE,
                   append = FALSE,
                   showNA = TRUE,
                   password = NULL)
        }
    arcgisrail("Agricultural products")


After reading the comments tried

arcgisrail <- function(i){
    Rail%>%
    filter(Commodity == i)%>%
    write.xlsx(paste("S:\\GradSchool\\Doctor of Philosophy\\Second Year\\RA - TT\\New folder\\Canada Freight Analysis\\FolderforARCGIS",i,sep="\\"),
               sheetName = "Sheet1",
               col.names = TRUE,
               row.names = TRUE,
               append = FALSE,
               showNA = TRUE,
               password = NULL
    )

}
```

but getting the error message

```
Error in createWorkbook(type = ext) : 
  Unknown format Agricultural products
```

Comment: use `paste` in your string

Comment: [`paste`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html) or [`sprintf`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sprintf.html) or [`glue::glue`](https://glue.tidyverse.org/) or ...

Answer (score 0):

```
arcgistruck <- function(i){
  ARCGISdata%>%
    filter( Mode=="Truck for-hire", Commodity == i)%>%
    write_xlsx(paste("c:\\New folder\\FolderforARCGIS\\Truck",i,sep="\\"),
               col_names = TRUE, format_headers = TRUE)
    }
```

Instead of using the function `write.xlsx` I used `write_xlsx`

This generated the file without the .xlsx at the end of the filename. So had to manually rename all the generated files and add .xlsx. Which was repetitive and painful